# Samba Shares Ubuntu 12.04 and Win 7 Home Network

Tags: networking, samba

I have managed to create a home network of sorts between my desktop with windows 7 and my laptop running Precise Pangolin using probably more than a dozen different tutorials I have read here and elsewhere on the net. I have installed and configured Samba, made my folders "shared" and basically done everything I had to do multiple times and what I have is the following:

Firstly, I can see the shared Windows folders from the Ubuntu machine but I can only access the Windows public folders - not the other shared folders. When I try and access the non-public shared folders, I get an error "Unable to mount drive". Is that normal - is one not supposed to access folders that are not public folders, even if the are shared?

Secondly, the Ubuntu folders are not even visible from Windows - it's not in the Windows network at all. (Maybe my procedure to make the Ubuntu folders is flawed. The tutorials all say right click the folder and select the share option in properties, but you can't do it that way in 12.04.)

So all I have is partial, one-way access between my two operating systems.

Can anyone shed some light on this? A re-cap on the steps and procedures to establish the network would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've done some more tweaking and now, when I click on the shared Win folders, I'm asked for a password. I have not set a username and password. I don't have a password for Windows and my samba username and password don’t work.

I still can't see my Ubuntu machine from Windows - even with the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I might be able to help with part of this.

When prompted with a username/password for the Windows share, it's asking for your **Windows** username and password. If you don't have a password set, you'll have to set one.